# After Resetting the array the color of bars remain green

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
import React, {
  useEffect,
  useState
} from "react";
import "./sortingVisualiser.css";

const rnadomIntFromInterval = (min, max) => {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
};

function waitforme(milisec) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve("");
    }, milisec);
  });
}

const SortVisualiser = () => {
  const [array, setArray] = useState([]);

  const resetArray = () => {
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      arr.push(rnadomIntFromInterval(5, 600));
    }
    setArray(arr);
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    resetArray();
  }, []);

  const bubbleSort = async() => {
    const a = document.getElementsByClassName("array-bar");
    let i = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < a.length - i - 1; j++) {
        a[j].style.background = "blue";
        a[j + 1].style.background = "blue";

        if (parseInt(a[j].style.height) >= parseInt(a[j + 1].style.height)) {
          await waitforme(1000);
          let temp1 = a[j].style.height;
          let temp2 = a[j + 1].style.height;
          temp1 = temp1.substring(0, temp1.length - 2);
          temp2 = temp2.substring(0, temp2.length - 2);
          a[j + 1].style.height = `${parseInt(temp1)}px`;
          a[j].style.height = `${parseInt(temp2)}px`;
        }
        a[j].style.background = "Turquoise";
        a[j + 1].style.background = "Turquoise";
      }
      a[a.length - 1 - i].style.background = "green";
    }
    a[0].style.background = "green";
  };

  return ( <
    div className = "array-container" > {
      array.map((value, idx) => {
        return ( <
          div className = "array-bar"
          style = {
            {
              backgroundColor: "Turquoise",
              height: `${value}px`
            }
          }
          key = {
            idx
          } >
          < /div>
        );
      })
    } <
    button onClick = {
      resetArray
    } > Generate New Array < /button> <
    button onClick = {
      () => bubbleSort()
    } > Bubble Sort < /button> <
    /div>
  );
};

export default SortVisualiser;
```

```
**
  const resetArray = () => {
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      arr.push(rnadomIntFromInterval(5, 600));
    }
    setArray(arr);
When I am resetting the array I am getting the previous green color not the default color**
```

---

```
**  useEffect(() => {
    resetArray();
  }, []);
Here I am initialising the array when the component mounts**
```

---

```
**  a[j].style.background = "blue";
        a[j + 1].style.background = "blue";
Here I am changing the currently comparing elements to blue**
```

---

```
**   a[j + 1].style.height = `${parseInt(temp1)}px`;
          a[j].style.height = `${parseInt(temp2)}px`;
Here I am updating the heights of current swapped bars**
```

---

```
** a[j].style.background = "Turquoise";
        a[j + 1].style.background = "Turquoise";
Here I am changing back the colors of swapped bars to default color**
```

---

```
**a[a.length - 1 - i].style.background = "green";
Setting the color of sorted bar to green**
```

**button onClick = {
resetArray
} > Generate New Array < /button> <
button onClick = {
() => bubbleSort()
} > Bubble Sort < /button>
Now after sorting the array I need to reset the array but when I am resetting the array
I am getting the bars of green color which should not be because as I am resetting the array I am updating the state variable which in to re renders the component so I when I re iterate through the array I should get the bars of Turquoise color but instead I am getting bars of green color **

Answer (score 0):

You are changing the inline styles already in your `bubbleSort` function. And again after rerender its taking its older value of inline styles. One solution could be to unmount the div and re-render. Or the workaround solution for now would be to change the styles again like below. And call this function in your `resetArray()` function

```
  const resetColor = () => {
    const a = document.getElementsByClassName("array-bar");
    for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < a.length - i - 1; j++) {
        a[j].style.background = "Turquoise";
        a[j + 1].style.background = "Turquoise";
      }
    }
  }
```